# How to replicate this plot with inverted axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I'm trying to reproduce this plot I saw on a paper. The original author did it in excel or sigmaplot, he doesn't remember anymore.

Using a `geom_area` won't produce exactly the same.

This is what I got so far:

```
a %>%
  filter(p.value < 0.05) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = time, y = p.value)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

But it does not look the same. I also tried `geom_ribbon` and `geom_bar`, but they look different. In the plot I want to replicate the data seems to be inversed, and I can't do that.

edit: oops forgot to link the data> here's a `dput` https://pastebin.com/XWbb7zjt

Comment: Provide a reproducible example. We don't have access to `a`

Comment: Also, explain what you exactly mean by "inverted axis".

Comment: inverted because it goes from 0.05 to 0 instead of the other way around. scale_y_reverse does that, but the plot from ggplot is not similar.

Comment: Looking at my ggplot, actually what I want to plot are the areas in blank between the black areas. They are not ploted, because the value there is 0, so ggplot makes no bar there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you needed to look more carefully into what `geom_area` actually does. It plots bars with the bottom at `ymin = 0` and the top at `ymax`, and is a special case of `geom_ribbon` which allows freer setting of `ymin`. This is the plot I think you want. Here we just tell `ggplot` to plot the bars between the p value and 0.05, which with the scale reversed is at the bottom of the chart. This is based off your comment above that you wanted the negative space in your provided plot; I don't really know what makes this reversed plot more readable.

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_data <- tbl %>%
  filter(p.value < 0.05)
ggplot(plot_data) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = time, ymin = p.value, ymax = 0.05)) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make the plot more readable.. it's just something I have to do. A simple line would be enough in my opinion. In any case thanks